# virtual host subdomain not working properly, points me to main domain

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos, httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName db.mydomain.co
#ServerAlias db.mydomain.co
DocumentRoot /var/www/db/public

<Directory /var/www/db/public>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/www/db/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/db/requests.log combined
```

It's the config file I created in cong.d directory. I also changed the host file on my PC pointing mydomain.co to the server IP address. After I restarted my apache server, I go to `db.mydomain.co` which gives me `db.mydomain.co’s server DNS address could not be found.` But ironically, `mydomain.co` shows me the subdomain content and I won't be able to access the website hosted on my main domain. I'm using the distribution made by Amazon, and it's based on CentOS I think.

I really have no idea what's going on here. Any helps appreciated.

Comment: db.mydomain.co does not have any DNS records, right? So, it won't work until you point the subdomain to your IP. On your PC, add the subdomain and its IP in the hosts file. Then browse again.

Comment: @nidhi It might not be the case, as now if I use IP address directly, I will get the subdomain website ranther than the main domain.

Comment: Yes. The IP address will work. The hostname ec2-something-amazon.com will also work. But for the subdomain to work, you will have to add it in your hosts file OR create DNS record for it.